# How can i persist with @Formula?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm calculating some properties of a table with ***@Formula***, and I want them to persist but I can't get them reflected in the database, that is, they persist. Is there a way to persist calculated properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `@Formula` annotation for this purpose, because how it's explained in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-formula):

> You can use a SQL fragment (aka formula) instead of mapping a property into a column. *This kind of property is read-only* (its value is calculated by your formula fragment)

I guess the `@ColumnTransformer` annotation is what you need.

This is an example from the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-read-and-write):

```java
@Column(name = "pswd")
@ColumnTransformer(
    read = "decrypt( 'AES', '00', pswd  )",
    write = "encrypt('AES', '00', ?)"
)
private String password;
```

Here `read` is the sql snippet that will be calculated during the `password` field initialization and `write` is the sql snippet that will be calculated during the `password` field saving (the result value will be saved in the `pswd` column).

Comment: Sorry , but i'm not understanding you. Would be better if you explain what read and write means there , and "decrypt or encrypt"

Comment: Ok, please show how you use `@Formula` and what value you want to store and where.

Comment: I have updated the answer, hope it will help.

Comment: so in the write field i should do a insert into statement?

Comment: To be honest, it is unclear for me what do you want to achieve. Usually, `@Formula` is used for small calculation based on the some columns from the target entity table. If then you want to make some small calculations and store value to the some column of the target entity then `@ColumnTransformer` is the right chose for you. If you need to use complex sql for calculation and then complex sql for inserting data then just move this logic outside of your entity.